# get and set values to a Map in jsp using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary

I have a Map Object,this Map Object has some values and i m populating these values on a jsp page  but the problem is that when i post the jsp page to another controller i want the same values to be present  in the map Object.

Map(Some values)--->controller--->jsp(Map+some additional values)----post----->another controller[want Map+additional values]

MailContent.java

```
public class MailContent {
private String from;
private String to;
private String[] toMany;
private Map<String,byte[]> attachements;

//getter setter
}
```

some.jsp

```
<f:form action="../hr/sendNotification" commandName="mailHolder">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>From:</label></td>
            <td><input class="inputq" type="text" name="from" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>To:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="inputq" name="to" id="to"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td><label>Subject:</label></td>
            <td><input class="inputq" type="text" name="subject" /></td>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach var="attach" items="${mailHolder.attachements }" varStatus="i">
            <tr>
                <td><label>Attachement:${i.index+1 }</label></td>
                <td><input class="inputq" type="text" value="${attach.value }" name="attachements[${i.index }].value"/>
                <input class="inputq" type="text" value="${attach.key }" name="attachements[${i.index }].key"/>

            </tr>



        </c:forEach>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Message:</label></td>
            <td><textarea class="tarea" cols="60" rows="10" name="message"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input class="fancy" type="submit" value="Send" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input class="fancy" type="reset"
                value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>






    </table>

</f:form>
```

The key value pair is displayed successfully on jsp but when i post it to another controller and get the values then the key part is filled with some index instead of value.

on console:

before:

```
MailContent [from=null, to=null, attachements={abc=[B@1d37913, xyz=[B@b20ff5}, subject=null, message=null]
```

Afetr post:

```
MailContent [from=from, to=to@gmail.com, attachements={0=[B@ebe064, 1=[B@1d90655}, subject=subject, message=message]
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: simple In jsp how to fill values in a Map.

Comment: *Manually* fill values in a Map or using BeanUtils.

Comment: Manually...there are input type's in jsp for every key value pair and map entries can be any no.

Comment: The jsp does know nothing about type, everything is a string.

Comment: the map is of type Map<String,byte[]>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36603/discussion-between-dinesh-and-roman-c)